# Matching on pre-treatment outcome $z$-score in diff-in-diff analysis to avoid regression toward the mean bias in $ATT$ estimates?

Tags: difference-in-difference, matching, z-score, counterfactuals, regression-to-the-mean

There have been many articles (e.g., [Chabé-Ferret (2017)](https://www.tse-fr.eu/sites/default/files/TSE/documents/doc/wp/2017/wp_tse_824.pdf), [Daw & Hatfield (2018)](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/29957834/), [Zeldow & Hatfield (2021)](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/33978956/)) discussing the perils of matching on pre-treatment outcomes (such as patient's medical cost or hospital utilization in healthcare studies) which have dissimilar distributions since regression toward the mean effects may cloud average treatment effect on the treated (ATT) estimates.

Would matching on the pre-treatment outcome $z$-scores rather then raw values remove any bias due to regression toward the mean?

Comment: Do you mean $z$-scores computed within each treatment group?

Comment: @Noah Yes, within the pre-treatment period. Would the parallel trend or baseline level assumption still be violated if you used $z$-scores?

Comment: Not sure, this is a good question; I just wanted to clarify. Consider asking in Pedro Sant'Anna's DiD [Twitter group](https://twitter.com/i/communities/1511900404040159232).

Comment: @Noah Cool thanks Noah